# Seclect specific fields from a column using python jupyter

Tags: python-3.x

based on the below sample data I am trying to write a code to select when Region =NA. Appreciate any help here.

#Sample data:
Region: ASPAC, NA, LATAM, EMEA

Comment: You need to specify which package you are using, is it pandas?

Comment: Where does your data come from? If it's a text file, please post an excerpt of it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Sample data:                                                                                                                 Region Date                PR Volume
NA          January 7, 2019 7
ASPAC January 7, 2019 14
ASPAC January 7, 2019 48
EMEA January 7, 2019 266
LATAM January 7, 2019 16
LATAM January 7, 2019 54

Comment: This is the code                                                                                                               
 # import the Pandas library and read contracting data into a data frame:
# Only when region =NA
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = C:\Users\Anne>mydata.py